# Can someone explain why/how Nodes from LinkedLists change without changing them directly in Java?

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

Sorry, the title of this question may not be entirely clear. I'm just having trouble understanding this sample question from my upcoming exam:

The following Node points to the following list of chars:
head -> [a] -> [b] -> [c] -> [d]

where the list nodes are instances of the following class

```
public class Node {
     public char value;
     public Node next;
}
```

What will be printed after the following code executes?

```
Node ptr1, ptr2, p;
ptr1 = head;
ptr2 = head.next;
ptr1.next = ptr2.next.next;
ptr2.next.next = ptr1;
p = head;
head = head.next;
while(p!=null){
    System.out.print(p.value + " ");
    p=p.next; 
}
```

Apparently the answer is **a d**. Can someone explain this to me?

These were my steps toward solving the problem:

```
ptr1 = head; //ptr1 -> [a]->[b]->[c]->[d]

ptr2 = head.next; //ptr2 -> [b]->[c]->[d]

prt1.next = ptr2.next.next; //prt1 -> [a]->[d]

prt2.next.next=prt1; //prt2 -> [b]->[c]->[a]->[d]

p=head; //p-> [a]->[b]->[c]->[d]

head=head.next; // head-> [b]->[c]->[d]
```

So I was thinking that the answer was just iterating over the original Node (a, b, c, d), which obviously isn't the case, I just don't understand at what point "head" became anything than it's original state. Do the Node variables change the original Node somehow? This doesn't make sense to me from everything I know about Java so far. Sorry if this is a stupid question I am just failing to understand and I haven't been able to find anything online regarding this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should **draw it on paper**, so you can see what's going on.

The sequence is as follows:

> ```
>  head → [a] → [b] → [c] → [d]
> ```

> **`ptr1 = head;`**
>
> ```
>        ptr1
>          ↓
>  head → [a] → [b] → [c] → [d]
> ```

> **`ptr2 = head.next;`**
>
> ```
>        ptr1  ptr2
>          ↓     ↓
>  head → [a] → [b] → [c] → [d]
> ```

> **`ptr1.next = ptr2.next.next;`**
>
> ```
>        ptr1  ptr2
>          ↓     ↓
>          ↓    [b] → [c]
>          ↓           ↓
>  head → [a] → → → → [d]
> ```

> **`ptr2.next.next = ptr1;`**
>
> ```
>        ptr1  ptr2
>          ↓     ↓
>          ↓    [b] → [c]
>          ↓           ↓
>  head → → → → → → → [a] → [d]
> ```

> **`p = head;`**
>
> ```
>        ptr1  ptr2
>          ↓     ↓
>          ↓    [b] → [c]
>          ↓           ↓
>  head → → → → → → → [a] → [d]
>                      ↑
>                      p
> ```

> **`head = head.next;`**
>
> ```
>        ptr1  ptr2        head
>          ↓     ↓           ↓
>          ↓    [b] → [c]    ↓
>          ↓           ↓     ↓
>           → → → → → [a] → [d]
>                      ↑
>                      p
> ```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for this visual. Really cleared things up. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You're correct up to this point.

```
prt2.next.next=prt1; //prt2 -> [b]->[c]->[a]->[d]
```

Then, on this next step, `head` hasn't changed. You're right about that. Now, `head` is pointing to `[a]` and always has been, so it's *still pointing to* `[a]`, even though `[a]` has moved somewhere else.

```
p=head; //p-> [a]->[d]
```

Then we assign `head` to `head.next`, but that doesn't even matter because we never use `head` again. So we're iterating over `[a]` then `[d]`, hence the output.